# How do I sign and send a versioned transaction using the wallet adapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, versionedtransactions, walletadapter

I have a versioned Transaction that I want to sign with my wallet and send.

Trying to use `signTransaction` and `sendTransaction` are giving me  the following errors

```
app-index.js:32 WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base/lib/esm/adapter.js:224:23)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/WalletProviderBase.js:161:16)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./app/create/page.tsx:203:31)
```

The logs aren't also revealing anything that could hint at the problem, which is another problem.

Is there a way I could resolved the above using the `wallet adaper` and if not, is there a way I could access the keypair instead so that I could just send the transaction using the `sendAndConfirmTransaction`